Outlier is duplicated in a different colour in smplot2
I'm plotting Torque for different timepoints but I can't seem to determine where these 2 duplicated outliers are coming from or how to remove them.
They are the 2 black dots in the "pre-m" Timepoint. I imagine some other layer is including outliers but I cant figure out what. Below is my code.
Any help is appreciated.
library(ggplot2)
library(smplot2) #https://github.com/smin95/smplot2

ggplot(data = match1, aes(x = Time.m.1, y = Rel.Torque.m.1, fill = Time.m.1)) +
  sm_raincloud(sep_level = 3, point.params = list(alpha = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Timepoints", y = "Relative Torque (Nm/kg)") 


I tried removing different layers and seeing if it would go away. I also set the alpha to 0 to see if that was the issue but those data points didn't correspond to that code.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Outliers in black colour is coming from geom_boxplot, we can pass outliers=FALSE to hide outliers from boxplot, try this example:
library(ggplot2)
library(smplot2) #https://github.com/smin95/smplot2

#example data from smplot2 website
#https://smin95.github.io/dataviz/slope-charts-point-plots-bland-altman-forests-rainclouds-histograms-part-2.html#raincloud-plot---sm_raincloud 
set.seed(2343) # generate random data
group1 <- abs(rnorm(20, 2.5, 1))
group2 <- abs(rnorm(20, 5, 1))
Subject <- rep(paste0("S", seq(1:20)), 2)
Data <- data.frame(Value = matrix(c(group1, group2), ncol = 1))
Group <- rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2"), each = length(group1))
df <- cbind(Subject, Data, Group)

# add outlier
df[1, "Value"] <- 7

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Group)) +
  sm_raincloud(sep_level = 3, point.params = list(alpha = 1),
               outliers = FALSE) # <--- here
               # or set outlier.shape = NA



Thank you so much! This worked! Really appreciate the help!
